# How to stop SVG animation on click?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, svg-animate

I have an svg animation, I want to be able to stop/pause the animation on click but I can't figure out how and I need help, I tried to toggle but I think I have to toggle each line which I don't know how to.

```
<div class="loader">
      <svg id="wave" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 38.05">
        <path id="Line_1" class="t" data-name="Line 1" d="M0.91,15L0.78,15A1,1,0,0,0,0,16v6a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V16a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H0.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_1" class="t" data-name="Line 2" d="M6.91,9L6.78,9A1,1,0,0,0,6,10V28a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V10A1,1,0,0,0,7,9H6.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_1" class="t" data-name="Line 3" d="M12.91,0L12.78,0A1,1,0,0,0,12,1V37a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H12.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_1" class="t" data-name="Line 4" d="M18.91,10l-0.12,0A1,1,0,0,0,18,11V27a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V11a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H18.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_1" class="t" data-name="Line 5" d="M24.91,15l-0.12,0A1,1,0,0,0,24,16v6a1,1,0,0,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V16a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H24.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_1" class="t" data-name="Line 6" d="M30.91,10l-0.12,0A1,1,0,0,0,30,11V27a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V11a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H30.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_1" class="t" data-name="Line 7" d="M36.91,0L36.78,0A1,1,0,0,0,36,1V37a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H36.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_1" class="t" data-name="Line 8" d="M42.91,9L42.78,9A1,1,0,0,0,42,10V28a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V10a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H42.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_1" class="t" data-name="Line 9" d="M48.91,15l-0.12,0A1,1,0,0,0,48,16v6a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V16a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H48.91Z"/>
      </svg>
      </div>
```

css

```
.loader {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
#wave {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  fill: black;
}
#wave.stop {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#Line_1 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
}
#Line_2 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
#Line_3 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
}
#Line_4 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
#Line_5 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
#Line_6 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
#Line_7 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.05s;
}
#Line_8 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
#Line_9 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.35s;
}
```

js

```
  var vawe = document.getElementById("vawe")
  vawe.addEventListener('click',function() {
    vawe.classList.toggle('stop');
     })
```

when I click on the svg I want to stop pause the animation, so that the music stop, and then click again the animation starts again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#wave.stop {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Doesn't apply the `animation-play-state` to the actually animated (line) elements.
The css rule should rather look something like this:

```
#wave.stop .t {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

I also recommend to use class selectors to **avoid unnecessarily high specificity**
(introduced by id selectors in your css rules).

```js
var wave = document.getElementById("wave")
wave.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('stop');
})
```

```css
.loader {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#wave {
  height: 10em;
  fill: black;
}

.stop {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.stop .t {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.t {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: pulse 1s infinite forwards;
  transform: scale(1, 0.5)
}

.Line_1 {
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
}

.Line_2 {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.Line_3 {
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
}

.Line_4 {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.Line_5 {
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}

.Line_6 {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.Line_7 {
  animation-delay: 1.05s;
}

.Line_8 {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.Line_9 {
  animation-delay: 1.35s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 0.5)
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1, 1)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 0.5)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg class="wave" id="wave" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 38.05">
        <path id="Line_1" class="t Line_1" data-name="Line 1" d="M0.91,15L0.78,15A1,1,0,0,0,0,16v6a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V16a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H0.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_2" class="t Line_2" data-name="Line 2" d="M6.91,9L6.78,9A1,1,0,0,0,6,10V28a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V10A1,1,0,0,0,7,9H6.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_3" class="t Line_3" data-name="Line 3" d="M12.91,0L12.78,0A1,1,0,0,0,12,1V37a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H12.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_4" class="t Line_4" data-name="Line 4" d="M18.91,10l-0.12,0A1,1,0,0,0,18,11V27a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V11a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H18.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_5" class="t Line_5" data-name="Line 5" d="M24.91,15l-0.12,0A1,1,0,0,0,24,16v6a1,1,0,0,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V16a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H24.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_6" class="t Line_6" data-name="Line 6" d="M30.91,10l-0.12,0A1,1,0,0,0,30,11V27a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V11a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H30.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_7" class="t Line_7" data-name="Line 7" d="M36.91,0L36.78,0A1,1,0,0,0,36,1V37a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V1a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H36.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_8" class="t Line_8" data-name="Line 8" d="M42.91,9L42.78,9A1,1,0,0,0,42,10V28a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V10a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H42.91Z"/>
        <path id="Line_9" class="t Line_9" data-name="Line 9" d="M48.91,15l-0.12,0A1,1,0,0,0,48,16v6a1,1,0,1,0,2,0s0,0,0,0V16a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H48.91Z"/>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the delay is required on resume, try this JavaScript alternative. The animation property of the element is individually set or unset depending upon the state.

```
let el = document.getElementById("vawe")
el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let value = 'unset';
    if ( e.currentTarget.classList.contains('stop') ) {
        e.currentTarget.classList.remove('stop');
        value = 'pulse 1s infinite';
    } else {
        e.currentTarget.classList.add('stop');
    }
    e.currentTarget.childNodes.forEach(child => {
        child.style.setProperty('animation-name', value);
    });
});
```

Comment: works but not perfect :) since it groups all paths the animation changes.

Comment: Your question does not specify how you want the animation to stop.

Comment: you can check animation delay is different on each of them!

Comment: Check the updated answer.